# Here's a tricky word code

Tags: cipher

The answer to this is unknown. See the bottom for its origin.
Can anyone decipher this collection of seemingly random words? There is likely a message encoded.
All I have noticed is that words are grouped in a (1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2) shape by commas, and the answer may (but may not) have some key in a pyramid shape.
Good luck! The title is mdpnfbo,jrfp and the code is:

> ed,,zinger suivante,,tels handknits finish,,cagefuls basinlike bag octopodan,,imbossing vaporettos rorid easygoingnesses nalorphines,,benzol respond washerwomen bristlecone,,parajournalism herringbone farnarkeled,,episodically cooties,,initiallers bimetallic,,leased hinters,,confidence teetotaller computerphobes,,pinnacle exotically overshades prothallia,,posterior gimmickry brassages bediapers countertrades,,haslet skiings sandglasses cannoli,,carven nis egomaniacal,,barminess gallivanted,,southeastward,,oophoron crumped,,tapued noncola colposcopical,,dolente trebbiano revealment,,outworked isotropous monosynaptic excisional moans,,enterocentesis jacuzzi preoccupations,,hippodrome outward googs,,tabbises undulators,,metathesizing,,sharia prepostor,,neuromast curmudgeons actability,,archaise spink reddening miscount,,madmen physostigmin statecraft neurocoeles bammed,,tenderest barguests crusados trust,,manshifts darzis aerophones,,reitboks discomposingly,,expandors,,monotasking galabia,,pertinents expedients witty,,chirographies crachach unsatisfactoriness swerveless,,flawed sepulchred thanksgiver scrawl skug,,perorate stringers gelatine flagstones,,chuses conceptualization surrejoined,,counterblasts rache,,numerative,,delirifacients methylthionine,,mantram dynamist atomised,,eternization percalines hryvnias pragmatizing,,reproachfulnesses telework nowts demoded revealer,,burnettize caryopteris subangular wirricows,,transvestites sinicized narcissus,,hikers meno,,degassing,,postcrises alikenesses,,sycophancy seroconverting insure,,yantras raphides cliftiest bosthoon,,zootherapy chlorides nationwide schlub yuri,,timeshares castanospermine backspaces reincite,,coactions cosignificative palafitte,,poofters subjunctions,,aquarian,,theralite revindicating,,cynosural permissibilities narcotising,,journeywork outkissed clarichords troutier,,myopias undiverting evacuations snarier superglue,,deaminise infirmaries teff hebephrenias,,brainboxes homonym lancelet,,lambitive stray,,inveigled,,acetabulums atenolol,,dekkos scarcer flensed,,abulias flaggers wammul boastfully,,galravitch happies interassociation multipara augmentations,,teratocarcinomata coopting didakai infrequently,,hairtails intricacy usuals,,pillorise outrating,,cataphoresis,,furnishings leglen,,goethite deflate butterburs,,phoneticising winiest hyposulphuric campshirts,,chainfalls swimmings roadblocked redone soliloquies,,broking mendaciousness parasitisms counterworld,,unravellings quarries passionately,,onomatopoesis repenting,,ramequin,,mopboard euphuistically,,volta sycophantized allantoides,,bors bouclees raisings sustaining,,diabolist sticks dole liltingly,,curial bisexualisms siderations hemolysed,,damnabilities unkenneling halters,,peripheral congaing,,diatomicity,,foolings repayments,,hereabouts vamosed him,,slanters moonrock porridgy monstruous,,heartwood bassoonist predispositions jargoon dominances,,timidest inalienable rewearing inevitably,,entreating retiary tranquillizing,,uniparental droogs,,allotropous,,forzati abiogenetic,,obduration exempted unifaces,,epilating calisaya dispiteously coggles,,vestmented flukily ignifying complished hiccupy municipalize,,pentagraphs parcels sutler excavates,,stardust miscited thankfulness,,fouter pertused,,overpacks,,guarishes hylotheism,,pi

The origin of this is a game that's very popular as of november 2017 called 'Doki doki Literature club', a creepy horror game full of codes and easter eggs about the game's sequel, only for those dedicated enough to find an answer. It has already be gleaned that the sequel will have something to do with a thing called 'project Libitina', with many hints as to what that is. This part of the game, which was a poem produced by one of the characters, has not, however, as yet revealed any information. Thank you for helping to try and find some.

Comment: looks like some sort of word-substitution code - impossible to make sense of without the key.

Comment: Here are likely keys:
Libitina,
Markov
Or possibly the decoded title 'mdpnfbo,jrfp'

Comment: This might just be a distraction away from the "poem" that comes after it (not appropriate for SE).

Comment: It might be, but it might not be, and I don't know enough about puzzle solving to make a good judgement on it, so I thought this might be a good place to ask

Answer (score 1):

All graphical glitches, text glitches, and anything messing up the UI is intentional. All squares and glitched out dialogue is all part of the game. There is a character in the game (seriously) that knows that she/he is in the game. He/she messes with the game.

My thought: You don't need to bother about it.
I think you should ask about it [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/doki-doki-literature-club). It seems more suitable.